# Count of cells in a certain column the does not contain a specified value

Tags: google-sheets-api

I can't find anywhere a function that would allow me to count every cell in a column except a certain value given.

For example there is a column where  the values are (-), 1, 2 and 3 , I want to count all the cells that are not "(-)".

So there should be a function like

```
=countif(A1:A100, Not "(-)")
```

Does anyone how to do that?

Comment: Perhaps this question would be a better fit for webapps.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using `<>` for not equal, like so:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A100, "<>-")
```

Replace the `-` with what you want to not count, and change `A1:A100` to the range of data you would like the formula to consider.